# Get full object from collection in API request fail

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get an object from the `Persons Collection` via API, but it returns only `null` for the related `Car` object.

Person Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime PersonPublicationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Car Model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CarPublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Get Method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetPersonData/{id}")]
public Person GetPerson([FromRoute] int id)
{
    Person personData = _context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    return personData;
}
```

---

In `personData` it returns only `null` when asked for a `Car`. I need in this place only one person data with his `Car` like this:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Jan Bojanowski",
    "city": "Warszawa",
    "salary": 1245,
    "personPublicationDate": "2018-02-02T00:00:00",
    "isActive": true,
    "car": {
        "id": 2,
        "carName": "Skoda",
        "carPublicationDate": "2018-10-01T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing simple query, the only data you will obtain is the object itself:

```
Person personData = _context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
```

To properly get the data, you must ask to include also the related object:

```
Person personData = _context.Persons
                            .Include(person => person.Car)
                            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
```

---

Recommended reading on this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data